# How to secure ActiveMQ in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, queue, activemq-classic

I want to secure my connection to ActiveMQ in Spring Boot. Currently Spring Boot is connecting to my ActiveMQ without any username and password, so I want to avoid this. So as per the resources I did these two things:

`activemq.xml`:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="securityPlugin" class="org.apache.activemq.security.SimpleAuthenticationPlugin">
        <property name="userMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="admin" value="password"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <broker xmlns="http://activemq.apache.org/schema/core" brokerName="localhost" dataDirectory="${activemq.data}">
        <plugins>
            <simpleAuthenticationPlugin anonymousAccessAllowed="false">
                <users>
                    <authenticationUser username="admin" password="password" groups="admins"/>
                </users>
                <groupMappings>
                    <groupMapping groupPrincipal="admins" roles="admins"/>
                </groupMappings>
            </simpleAuthenticationPlugin>
        </plugins>
        <transportConnectors>
            <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616"/>
        </transportConnectors>
    </broker>
</beans>
```

`application.properties`:

```
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=password
spring.activemq.packages.trust-all=true
spring.activemq.packages.trusted=com.hfc.card.config
spring.activemq.pool.enabled=false
spring.activemq.in-memory=true
spring.activemq.pool.enabled=false
spring.activemq.pool.max-connections=10
spring.activemq.broker-url=activemq.xml
```

After providing all these things still Spring Boot is able to connect to ActiveMQ without using username and password. Is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an authorization plugin and settings to define security access to certain queues and topics.

see Authorization: https://activemq.apache.org/security.html